# Check if two arrays have equal elements in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Given two arrays: `actual` and `expected`; is there a more efficient way to write the is equal check?

```
actual.reduce((total, element)=> {
        if (element !== expected[actual.indexOf(element)]) {
            return total = false;
        } else return total;
    },true);
```

Comment: Can you add a bit more detail and possibly a working example? Are you checking if all items in one array are present in another? Are duplicate values allowed? Are any of the arrays sorted?

Comment: you can also do it like `JSON.stringify(actual.sort()) === JSON.stringify(expected.sort())`

Answer (score 3):

A couple of things about your implementation:

1. `indexOf` will return the index of the first matching element. If there are duplicate elements it will fail- for example, the. comparison of  `1,2,1,4` and `1,2,3,4`.
2. Most (if not all) JavaScript array methods pass the current index to the callback function, so you could write your code as:

   ```
   actual.reduce((total, element, index)=> {
   ```
3. Ideally, you want to stop when you have found a pair that doesn't match.

However I would do this using the `every` method:

```
let equal = actual.length == expected.length 
         && actual.every((element, index)=> element === expected[index] );
```

(Or possibly with a plain old *for* loop)